# can't execute opatch even I'm in the oinstall group with -rwx--x---

Tags: oracle, linux

I'm in `$ORACLE_HOME/OPatch` directory and 
I type `opatch`.  It responds:

```
bash: opatch: command not found
```

if I do `./opatch`:

```
/bin/sh: ./opatch: Permission denied
```

`ls -l opatch` shows `-rwx--x---` so for group the user which is `oinstall`, it should have the execute right.

`id -g` does show me in the `oinstall` group.

So why I can't execute `opatch` in this case?

Comment: The group doesn't have read permission. Run `chmod g+r opatch` or `chmod 750 opatch`.

Answer (score 3):

First, let me state that I think that running anything as the non-oracle user on your filesystem may result in significant database issues! (I'll explain why in a minute)

Aside from the pathing issue, which you solved, I think that Colin is correct. You (or your admin) does need to give read on the binary:

```
[root@db01 ~]# useradd captjackvane
[root@db01 ~]# groups captjackvane
captjackvane : captjackvane
[root@db01 ~]# usermod -a -G oinstall captjackvane
[root@db01 ~]# groups captjackvane
captjackvane : captjackvane oinstall

[captjackvane@db01 OPatch]$ ls -ltrh opatch
-rwx--x--- 1 oracle oinstall 31K Mar 26  2013 opatch
[captjackvane@db01 OPatch]$ ./opatch lsinventory
/bin/sh: ./opatch: Permission denied

oracle@db01:(psu1) ~]$ chmod 750 ./opatch
oracle@db01:(psu1) ~]$ ls -ltrh opatch
-rwxr-x--- 1 oracle oinstall 31K Mar 26  2013 opatch

[captjackvane@db01 OPatch]$ ./opatch lsinventory
chmod: changing permissions of `/u01/oracle/app/product/db_1/.patch_storage': Operation not permitted
The chmod command failed for ./u01/oracle/app/product/db_1/.patch_storage.. It is possible that you have no permission to access it. OPatch cannot proceed!
OPatch returns with error code = 1
```

As you can see, I can now "execute" the binary, but other permissions issues remain. So here's where I get to my first point:

Running things, especially anything that stops/starts a database and/or the cluster as someone other than the Oracle user can lead to serious issues. I remember in my career-youth I accidentally started a development database as my physical user, instead of Oracle. Which meant that many (but not all) of the processes used by the database had my name on them (and by extension, my permissions) instead of Oracle.

Your best bet here is to use the Oracle user, or ask your admin to complete whatever the task is for you.

Answer (score 1):

Not an Oracle issue, but this is how permissions on scripts work.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34202/can-a-script-be-executable-but-not-readable

> `ls -l opatch` shows `-rwx--x---` so for group the user which is
>   oinstall, it should have the execute right.

And you have it. But the interpreter needs to read the script, and you do not have the privilege for that.

Execute permission without read permission is enough on executable binary files.

But `opatch` is not an executable binary file, actually it is a script that runs `java`. Yes, there are workarounds, but `opatch` comes with `-rwxr-x---` by default.

So the real question is, who and why set it to `-rwx--x---` on your system, because it should be `-rwxr-x---`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me the solution was typing ./opatch instead of opatch at the linux command prompt.

This is the way to initiate an executable and it won't start with just typing the name.

Comment: They tried this, as seen from the question.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolved by setting the path environment variable.
Before setting the environment:

```
[oracle@oracle 35643107]$ opatch version
bash: opatch: command not found
```

---

Run thew below to set the path:

```
$ export PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/db_1/OPatch:$PATH
$ echo $PATH
*/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/db_1/OPatch*:/home/oracle/.local/bin:/home/oracle/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/db_1/bin
[oracle@oracle 35643107]$ opatch version
OPatch Version: 12.2.0.1.40

OPatch succeeded.
```

Please note that I am in the directory where the patch is being unzipped.